# Cache reading fails in Xamarin.iOS with Akavache

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, akavache

In a cross-platform project we use Akavache as our cache. The target is .Net Standard 2.1, and we use version 6.10.20.

We simply use the following for writing:

`await cache.InsertObject(userIDKey, userID);`

For reading:
`await cache.GetObject<Guid>(userIDKey);`

It works on *Xamarin.Android*, for both reading and writing.

Unfortunately, we can *only write* in **Xamarin.iOS** (the cache does contain the item).

When we try to read it, the following exception occurs:

> Operation is not supported on this platform.
>
> Stacktrace:   at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor (System.String name, System.Reflection.MethodAttributes attributes, System.Reflection.CallingConventions callingConvention, System.Type returnType, System.Type[] parameterTypes, System.Type owner, System.Boolean skipVisibility) [0x00006] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection.Emit/DynamicMethod.notsupported.cs:74 \n  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ILEmitResolverBuilder.BuildTypeNoCache (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite callSite) [0x00038] in :0 \n  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ILEmitResolverBuilder.BuildType (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite callSite) [0x00055] in :0 \n  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ILEmitResolverBuilder.Build (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite callSite) [0x00039] in :0 \n  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CompiledServiceProviderEngine.RealizeService (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite callSite) [0x00006] in :0 \n  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>n__0 (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite callSite) [0x00000] in :0 \n  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__1 () [0x00000] in :0 \n  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534 \n  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 \n"

We use the following environment:

- OS:       iOS 13.5
- Device:   Simulator 11.5
- Xamarin: 16.6.000.1062 (d16-6@41e1f0e)
- Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   13.18.2.1 (29c4ea7)

It is very strange that writing works yet the same object can't retrieve the data.

What could cause this?

Comment: It is not a Akavache failure, the DependencyInjection/ServiceLookup you are using is trying to emit IL and that is not allowed by iOS (`DynamicMethod.notsupported`), i.e. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection is not iOS safe, there is a "preview" version of that library available, but I'm not sure if that does anything to help on iOS, you can always open an issue @ https://github.com/dotnet/extensions

Comment: @SushiHangover Still strange that the dependency injection works when I get the cache for writing.